# Autosize for cell in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In my cell I have Title label and description label. Description label can be small and big. I use for it `descriptionLabel.sizeToFit()`, but how to use the same for cell. If cell.sizeToFit() doesn't work

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as!  ExercisesCollectionViewCell

        let workouts = exercises[indexPath.item]
        cell.titleLabel.text = workouts.titleExercise
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = workouts.descriptionExercise
        cell.descriptionLabel.sizeToFit()
        cell.sizeToFit()

    return cell
}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIPKB.png)

Comment: Why would you do that to cell ?

Comment: And how to change the size of the cell dynamically?

Comment: @Dhruv or I should use smth another ?

Comment: Could you add some image/ code or something that can show what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Dhruv Yes, I've done it

Comment: @Rozgen Provide more context to what you want to achieve. Also posting code with what you have tried and what part is not working will help community members understand your difficulty better.

Comment: @RohanSanap added code and image from simulator

Comment: @Rozgen If you want each cell to be a single row, use `UITableView` instead of `UICollectionView`

Comment: @Rozgen setting `UITableView`'s `rowHeight` to automatic will solve your problem

Comment: @RohanSanap okay, I'll try. But how to do the same in collection view ?

Comment: @Rozgen you will have to do lot of calculations in case of collections views. Checkout collection view flow layout delegates if you really want to do it using collection views.

Answer (score -1):

> Use UITableview instead of UICollectionView

First you have to count the number of lines of UILabel

```
 NSInteger lineCount = 0;
 CGSize textSize = CGSizeMake(yourLabel.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT);
 int rHeight = lroundf([yourLabel sizeThatFits:textSize].height);
 int charSize = lroundf(yourLabel.font.lineHeight);
 lineCount = rHeight/charSize;
 NSLog(@"No of lines: %i",lineCount);
```

else you can take extension to count max line of label

```
extension UILabel {
    func calculateMaxLines() -> Int {
        let maxSize = CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: CGFloat(Float.infinity))
        let charSize = font.lineHeight
        let text = (self.text ?? "") as NSString
        let textSize = text.boundingRect(with: maxSize, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], context: nil)
        let linesRoundedUp = Int(ceil(textSize.height/charSize)) 
        return linesRoundedUp
    }    
}
```

Use that:

```
let lineCount = YourLabel. calculateMaxLines
```

Now Set the height for each line of label

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return lineCount * 18 //If total 3 line so 3*18 = 54 is height else you can take any number instead of 18 according to font size height
}
```

Comment: Setting up AutoLayout, setting number of lines as 0 for descriptionLabel and setting rowHeight to automatic should do all the work.